# Viewing console output from TVJS

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'm working with the tvOS beta 3 and trying to do some basic debugging on the tvml/tvjs side of things.

Messages logged via **console.log(...)** in my js files don't appear in the main Xcode output window.

Is there somewhere else I can find these messages or a setting which needs to be configured?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should actually use the debug console in Safari. (The developer forum suggests you use Safari 9 and upgrade to El Capitan, both of which I have so haven't been able to test with inferior version)

Open Safari > Develop menu > Simulator
Your app name should appear here once and from there you can use the console.

Give it a few seconds to appear, it's not always instantaneous.

Comment: doesn't appear as an option for me, just says 'no inspectable applications'

Comment: You might just need to enable 'develop menu' by going to Safari >> preferences >> Advanced >> 'Show develop menu in menu bar'

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a hybrid application (TVML/TVJS + Swift) with [TVMLKitchen](https://github.com/toshi0383/TVMLKitchen) you can implement a logging function in Swift and use it in the TVJS code. For my projects I use the following code:

```
Kitchen.appController.evaluateInJavaScriptContext({context in
    let printInJS : @convention(block) (NSString!) -> Void = {
        (string : NSString!) -> Void in
            print("Log: \(string)\n")
    }
    context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(printInJS, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "printInJS")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give a name to the Bundle Identifier in General/Identity  (com.yourcompany.appname) to appear the app in the developers tool.